# Which one is correct: "subscribe to a membership" or "subscribe for a membership"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Can you please tell which one is correct: *subscribe to a membership* or *subscribe for a membership*? For example:

> If you subscribe **to** our membership, you'll get a discount of every product you buy at our store.
>
> If you subscribe **for** our membership, you'll get a discount of every product you buy at our store.

I haven't been able to find an answer on the internet. I think both maybe be correct. If so, is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: Why do you think "subscribe" collocates with "membership"? I wouldn't say it does. "Subscribe" collocates with things that you get on a subscription basis. Memberships don't work on a subscription basis.

Comment: @gotube would you please tell me what "membership" collocates with?

Comment: There's ["buy/purchase"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subscribe+to+a+membership%2Cpurchase+a+membership%2Cbuy+a+membership&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that OP's specific example ***membership*** is qualified by ***our*** is syntactically irrelevant (it could just as well be ***this** membership*, or some "unqualified" membership). So [here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subscribe%20to%20membership%2Csubscribe%20for%20membership&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) the relevant usage chart...

[image]

There no significant difference in preference, so use whichever you like. Personally, I much prefer...

> *If you **subscribe**, [then] **as a member,** you'll get...*

...on purely stylistic grounds. But it does also sidestep the "choice of preposition" problem!

Comment: Weird, "subscribe for * membership" is completely ungrammatical to me. Flipping through your ngram it seems to be a bit legalistic.

Comment: Like I said above, I don't like either of them. But I think "ungrammatical" is a bit extreme. Whatever - as [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subscribe+to+membership%2Csubscribe+for+membership%2Ctake+out+membership%2Csign+up+for+membership&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) both ***take out** membership* and ***sign up for** membership* are much more common than *subscribe [prep] membership*. But I think the important point for OP to note is *both prepositions are fine.* (Or *equally bad*, depending on how you look at it! :)

Comment: Can you interpret the (not pictured) frequency in this ngram? I agree with @AzorAhai-him- that this construction is just wrong.

Comment: @cruthers: As the chart in my previous comment makes clear, *to subscribe [prep] membership* is an "uncommon" construction, whatever preposition is used. But imho it's ridiculous / pointless to say the usage is "wrong". Sure - It's ***not very idiomatic*** (and never really  was). But you couldn't possibly cite any syntactic principle that it violates. Note that *part* of the reason native speakers don't like it is as gotube comments - we expect "things subscribed to" to be "things delivered on a regular / continuous basis", but "membership" doesn't really meet that expectation.

Comment: Is "I subscribed in a membership" wrong or just non-idiomatic? No one says it. It sounds wrong to native speakers. What's ridiculous is to insist that breaking a syntactic rule is "wrong" while staunchly defending breaking an established usage from this designation. It's pedantry. Learners don't care about this distinction and neither do I.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at. There's no "syntactic rule" saying that only certain prepositions can be used after the verb ***to subscribe***. Learners (and some native speakers) need to understand that there's a world of difference between "non-idiomatic" and "ungrammatical". In the final analysis there is ***no*** "correct" preposition that can naturally be used to link ***to subscribe*** and ***membership***, because native speakers today don't usually use *any* version of that construction...

Comment: as the chart linked to in my first comment shows, ***take out** a subscription* is a far more common usage. Basically, OP is asking the wrong question - rather than *Which preposition should be used here?*, it should be *How do native speakers phrase this?*

Comment: What I'm getting at is: "I subscribed in a membership" is wrong. If you refuse to call this wrong because it doesn't violate a "syntactic rule," then you're the one being ridiculous.

Comment: Why are you so preoccupied with getting me to say *I subscribed **in** a membership* is "wrong"? My answer explains to learners that it's a waste of time trying to establish which of ***to*** or ***for*** to use here, but I never mentioned ***in*** anyway. Since you've brought it up, though, I'll just point out that [*to subscribe **in** {a company}*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22subscribe+in+the+company%22) is far from unknown. That sort of usage is irrelevant to *learners*, but you can't just claim any usages *you're* not familiar with are "syntactically invalid".